# jQuery hide & show is too indiscriminate more precision needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make unique contact card that take a user's name and description from a `<input>` tag and `.append()`'s the input information within a `<div>` tag.

The logical progression should go like this...

1. User enters first & last name and description of their self.
2. When user clicks the "Add User" button it should only show the user's first and last name on the contact card.
3. When the contact card itself is clicked, it should hide the first & last name info and show *only* the description of the user.

My HTML...

```
<form>
    <h3>First name: <input id="f-name" class="border-rad" type="text"></input></h3>
    <h3>Last name: <input id="l-name" class="border-rad" type="text"></input></h3>
    <h3 id="description-h3">Description:</h3>
    <textarea id="text" class="border-rad" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
</form>
<button class="border-rad">Add User</button>
<div id="right-container"></div>
```

My jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
         $("#right-container").append("<div id='name' class='contact-cards'>" + $('#f-name').val() + " " + $('#l-name').val() + "<br> Click For Description</div><br>");
         $("#right-container").append("<div class='contact-cards description'>" + $('#text').val() + "</div>")
         $(".description").hide();
     });

     $(document).on('click', '#name', function(){
          $(this).hide();
          $(".description").show();
     });
});
```

I almost have it, but when I click on one contact card to show that specific description for that specific user's card, it shows *all* of the user's descriptions at once. It shouldn't do this. It should only show a specific user's description when the card is clicked on.

Check the screenshots below for a visual representation of the current functionality of the contact cards...

[Before card is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPBwJ.png)

[After card is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN1s6.png)

Comment: Any chance to set a snippet on the question or a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet https://jsfiddle.net/erikasland/peew3zhz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue you are having is that the selection $('.description') inside the onclick callback returns multiple elements, since every div you create for the description will have that class name.   So you just need a way to discriminate the div that applies to the current contact.

You can do this in a number of ways, and here is one.
Just change the call to show() inside the onclick callback to the following:

```
$(this).nextAll().eq(1).show();
```

The call to nextAll() will return br tag as the first element, so you need to pick the second one, i.e. eq(1).

Comment: It is working for me - the when you click on "Click For Description" the first and last names are hidden and the description is shown in a gray background.   All other contacts stay as is. What exactly do you get?

Comment: Oops! It does work. 
Could you explain the meaning of your code piece by piece to me? I need to understand this stuff. :)

Comment: The call to nextAll() returns all elements that are siblings to the current element (this).  Siblings are elements that have the same parent element.  So the list of elements returned by nextAll() has the br tag first followed by the description div (and more if there are additional contacts after the current one).  Then when you call eq() with an index of 1, eq(1), you are simply selecting the second item on this list, which is the description div.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the html in a variable and then use `.html(theHtml)` instead of append, or you could use `.empty()` before your first append, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/peew3zhz/1/

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("#right-container").empty().append("<div class='contact-container' <div id='name' class='contact-cards'>" + $('#f-name').val() + " " + $('#l-name').val() + "<br> Click For Description</div></div><br>");
    $("#right-container").append("<div class='contact-cards description'>" + $('#text').val() + "</div>")
    $(".description").hide();
});
```

Comment: This answer only produces one card and doesn't reveal the description once it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Ids should always be unique on a single page. When adding a new user, you are always giving the name div the id "name" as opposed to a unique identifier for that user, such as "name-1". jQuery is only hiding the first instance of "#name" as a result.

However, once you have clicked the imprecise "#name", you are asking all of the divs with class name "description" to be shown, not just the one next to the name you have clicked.

I would give the name div a class "contact-cards name". Then use the class for the click event. Then use siblings() to find only the description that is the sibling div of the name div that has been clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', '.name', function(){
     $(this).hide();
     $(this).siblings(".description").show();
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. 
When you click on the card every description shows up.